# Postgres - using DISTINCT ON to get first row, but also getting the COUNT(*) work

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON()
```

to return a particular row from a group of rows. Works well. But what I also want to return is the "COUNT(*)". So it might look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(name)
  name, num_items, COUNT(name)
FROM customers
ORDER BY name, num_items DESC
```

But of course, I get an error saying "name should be in a GROUP BY aggregate function".

How can I achieve the same result with the "count()" included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `count` as window function:

```
select distinct on (name)
    name, num_items, count(*) over(partition by name)
from customers
order by name, num_items desc;
```

or in your case you can just use `group by` name and use simple aggregation:

```
select
    name, max(num_items), count(*)
from customers
group by name
order by name
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b33cd/4)</kbd>**